# Postgres - distinct query slow over 5 million data

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I am trying to do a select distinct on a table with 5 millions of data which is taking approximately 2 minutes. My intent is to improve the speed to to seconds. [image]

Query: - select distinct accounttype from t_fin_do where country_id='abc'

---

Tried composite index, the cost just went up [image]

Comment: Please do not post the execution plan as an image. Paste it as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. To do that, copy the text result and paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? I am surprised that this isn't a parallel plan

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a partial and covering index for this query with:

```
 create index on t_fin_do(country_id, accounttype) where country_id='abc';
```

Depending on the selectivity of `country_id` this could be faster than a table seq scan.

Comment: From the original plan "*rows removed by filter: 3*" - the query has to go through all rows